# After presenting two viewcontrollers it is not dismissing to the root view in ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

This is what I have created one custom class which inherits UINavigationController

CustomNavigationController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@end
```

CustomNavigationController.m

```
#import "CustomNavigationController.h"

@interface CustomNavigationController ()

@end

@implementation CustomNavigationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}


@end
```

Parent view Controller

```
- (IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender
{
    FirstVC_New *firstVCOBJ = [[FirstVC_New alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstVC_New" bundle:nil];

    CustomNavigationController *navController = [[CustomNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstVCOBJ];
    navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
}
```

On Button click I am presenting new UIViewController.
This stuff of code I have done for FirstVC_New.

```
#pragma mark - Orientation methods.

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (IBAction)btnNextSelected:(id)sender
{
    SecondVC *secondVCOBJ = [[CouponDetailVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"CouponDetailVC" bundle:nil];

    CustomNavigationController *navController = [[CustomNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:couponDetailVCOBJ];
    navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
}
```

This stuff of code I have done in SecondVC.

```
#pragma mark - Orientation methods.

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

Now presenting from both the views are working perfectly. Main issue is that I am not able to go to the main root view from SecondVC by

either this way

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

or this way

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Suggest me the appropriate way for this issue, how can it be solved with iOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this methode

```
[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I hope it will work for you and navigate you to root view controller.